# Karate + Appium, command driver.startRecordingScreen() is not working

Tags: karate

There is a problem with sending startRecordingScreen() command with Karate to Appium server.

I tried to send command with curl and it works, but with in Karate scenario it's failed. No any logs on Appium server console

```
Feature: Simple test with appium

Background:
    * url 'http://127.0.0.1:4723'
    * configure driver = {type : 'android'}
    * def driverCaps = {"app":".../.app","newCommandTimeout":180, "platformVersion": "6.0", "platformName": "Android","deviceName":"Android Emulator", "avd":"avd_name"}

Scenario: Simple scenario

Given driver driverCaps
And driver.startRecordingScreen()
And driver.click('..')
```

It looks some Appium commands are not implemented in Karate?

Comment: So there is 'Karate' ... maybe we should include 'UFC' too :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes Appium is certainly experimental and it will take time unless you or anyone else can contribute. We are right now focusing on getting web-UI automation production-ready. It is shaping up quite well, so in my (biased) opinion - it is worth investing time in to extend to mobile + desktop automation.